# How create seekbar like on picture?

Tags: android, seekbar

How create a seekbar like the one shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: How to insert `android custom seekbar` in the Google search bar?

Answer (score 0):

you can create it like below:

```
     <SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_drawable"/>
```

and add your custom drawable as thumb.